# What if the counter exceeds the memory allocated by malloc or calloc

Tags: c

I use following command in C to allocates 80 bytes (in a 64bit system) to d.

```
double *d = calloc(10, sizeof(double));
```

And using following loop to initialize d

```
for (k=0;k<11;k++){
d[k] = k;
}
```

When I run the program, there is no error. but I feel since the upper limit on `k` is `11`, there should be something wrong as d is array of length 10.
Please let me know why the program is executed with no error.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a good chance of getting `segmentation fault` if your compiler is `gcc`

Comment: Ask for space for _10_ `double`s, and store _11_ there. See the problem? Besides, you are asking for space for 10 `double`s, that probably is 80 bytes, but no guarantee.

Answer (score 8):

This is [**undefined behavior**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). There might be an error, and it might be silently ignored by the OS, when you break the rules - all bets are off.

What actually happens in the code depends on the OS, the compiler and the architecture you run it on, which might be tolerant to this violation, crash or do something else, the point is - the resulting behavior is undefined.

Comment: This answer doesn't explain what the problem is. Otherwise A-OK.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that C and C++ doesn't do boundary checks with array and pointers as long as it is in the program stack. I believe it throws segmentation fault when access is outside the program stack.

Comment: No, it's *undefined behavior*;  there is no guarantee of a seg fault. See the other answer. And damn ... I'm out of votes.

Comment: Don't believe! The standard doesn't _forbid_ boundary checks, but doesn't mandate them ever. A few C/C++ compilers do boundary checking, the vast majority doesn't.